# How to fix: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, translation, google-translate

I am running the following code:-

```
from googletrans import Translator, constants
from pprint import print


# init the Google API translator
translator = Translator()

# translate a spanish text to english text (by default)
translation = translator.translate("Hola Mundo")


print("{} ({}) --> {} ({})".format(translation.origin, translation.src, translation.text, translation.dest))
```

While running this code, I got the error as : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

I can't figure out how to fix this error.

I have seen other answers on stackoverflow but those are not useful.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Following is the screenshot of the complete error:-
[image: Error that I got after running this code]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this error,  you have to uninstall the current **googletrans** version and install the new one using the following commands:

```
pip3 uninstall googletrans
pip3 install googletrans==3.1.0a0
```

Run the code again and it should fix the error.

Answer (score -2):

Installing using PyPI will install version 3.0.0, which has some errors. Later versions have been fixed. **Installing version 3.1.0a0 or 4.0.0rc1** will solve the problem. Please uninstall and then specify the version to install.

```py
pip uninstall googletrans
pip install googletrans==4.0.0rc1
```

[Release history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx9fu.png)